# Get data from regular form inputs alongwith contents in div

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a little email system on my wordpress site wherein people submit php generated content to me via email. Basically the content is generated within a div and then via a little javascript the div-content is mailed to me. I am skipping the part how it is generated in order to keep the focus on the main issue. Here is an illustration.

```
<div id="article" style="display:none">
   // some content are generated here via php
</div>

<div id="visitor">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="60"/>
</div>


<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onClick="handleFormSubmit()">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             function handleFormSubmit(){
             var button = document.getElementById('button');
             button.style.display = 'none';
         }
      </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('#button').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/processForm.php',
         data:{'message':$('#article').html(),'client': $('#visitor').html() },
                success:function(data) {
                alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
                      }           
                  });
               });
           });
 </script>
```

> Please note the first div-id"aricle" block, it contains the main
>   content, which I have been getting fine Now notice the second div-id
>   "visitor" block right below the first block. I have not been able to
>   get the input of that one. I would prefer to get it as a regular form text input.

I think the reason I am not able to get the input is because I am not having any `<form></form>` tag. But then the main part is working, so I just need it work along-with it somehow. I leave it upto you guys to suggest me solution or a best way to **get both the data.** I am familiar with a little php but javascript, not at all.

Here is the content of the processForm.php. All these have been put together by learning what I could from several articles on the web. Many thanks in advance.

```
$to = "emailto@awesomepeople.com";
  $subject  = "NEW ARTICLE";
  $message .= $_POST['message'];
  $client   = $_POST ['client'];
  $headers = "From: awesomesite <someone@website.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";           
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just sharing the code below to get the value of required textbox in the provided `div` id = "visitor", I hope it helps to get your desired results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {<br/>

         $('#button').click(function(){<br/>

         $.ajax({<br/>
         type: 'POST',<br/>
         url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/processForm.php',<br/>
         data:<br/>{<br/>'message':$('#article').html(),<br/>'client': $('#name').val() <br/>},<br/>
                success:function(data) <br/>{<br/>
                alert('You data has been successfully e-mailed');
<br/>                      }           
     <br/>             });
          <br/>     });<br/>
           });<br/>
 </script>
```

I have replaced `$('#visitor').html()` to `$('#name').val()` in your script, as the below is the explanation:

- `$('#visitor').html() =` gives the inner HTML content of that `div` of id = "visitor" which is a text box and I am sure that you are interested in the value entered by any user into that text box.
- `$('#name').val() =` gives you the value of text box whose id = "name"

I hope the above will help you to get desired results with explanation.

Comment: So I do not need to add `<form></form>` tags, right? Also please allow me a few minutes to test this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you do not need to add <form></form> tags untill you need to fetch a lot form attributes. As in your case only single text box value required to access & that can be achieved by ("#name").val().

Comment: Hi, I am still not getting the value of the field. Are You sure my email php block is alrite? What else could be wrong ?

Comment: $to = "emailto@awesomepeople.com";
  $subject  = "NEW ARTICLE";
  $message .= $_POST['message'];
  $message .= $_POST ['client'];
  $headers = "From: awesomesite <someone@website.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";           
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: Use the above code in sending emails... as you have declared $client = $_POST['client'] and that $client variable didn't concatenated anywhere with the $message variable. that's why I have used only single $message variable & used at all places to get all the values and that should be used in this ideal way only.

Comment: thanks a lot. The job is done. I also wanted to ask what if I can add a few more fields in future. Can this be integrated with form, if so how ? I would really appreciate an answer and nonetheless I am marking this as accepted. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can either use the above mentioned method for additional form fields in same manner or can use 'formValues': $('#myForm').serialize(); where myForm is id of your form & can access formValues in your php file.